# .htaccess authentication - Can I fetch IP list from a file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

I have multiple websites on my server and have .htaccess authentication on quite a few. I have excluded the authentication for specific IP addresses and it works perfectly.

Although what I would love to have is a common file for allowed IP addresses which I can reference in the various .htaccess files, so I can manage the list from one place and do not have to make changes to all the files individually.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

Regards,
Pratik

Comment: Loks like it could very well be possible. Apache makes all you need available:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html has all you'd need. But I've never done it before - but if you get no other responses, it's a place to start looking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep a list of `Allow from <ip>` in a separate file and access it via an htaccess file. You can do that inside of a `<Directory>` block in your vhost/server config using the `Include` directive, but not from htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common script to ban or allow IP address. Here is one example.
http://tips-scripts.com/ip_control